# All radio buttons are getting selected under a radio group, android

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to android and I have an xml like this:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/cardRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cardEditText">
</RadioGroup>
```

I'm tyring to inflate this xml using my code to generate as many radio buttons I want depending on my data model.

The code I use is (which is inside a for loop) :

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_payment_content_node,null);

        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) currentView.findViewById(R.id.cardRadioGroup);
        RadioButton rb =  new RadioButton(this);
        //set radiobutton properties
        rb.setText(entry.getKey());
        rb.setId(++radioButtonIdCounter);

        rg.addView(rb);

        //add to view
        parent.addView(currentView);
```

This is working as expected. But the problem is that I can select many radio buttons at a time on my device.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you adding your newly created radio buttons to the radio group?

Comment: I didn't add. How can I add those? Android doesn't know that `cardRadioButton` is inside the `RadioGroup` named `cardRadioGroup`?

Comment: @siriam How would you expect to be able to add GUI elements dynamically in XML? Special looping tags would be required to be able to provide the resulting objects with individual properties. XSLT could be used but Android will not apply XSLT to your layout descriptions. YOu could do that manually but it's more efficient to add the buttons programmartically, as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of your buttons have the same ID. That's why they act so uniformly.

You would inflate the layout only once. You'd have to add the buttons programmatically by identifying `cardRadioGroup` and then looping in code, generating unique IDs for all buttons.

To add radio buttons to the group, use [RadioGroup.addview()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29).

To create the radio buttons, use one of the constructors of [RadioButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html) and set further properties if required.

Comment: @siriam SOunds like you still have a radio button in your XML, or add always the same button. You can't do that. Start with _no_ radio buttons in XML and create _all of them_ via RadioButton constructors. They need to be individual objects.

Comment: I did this way `RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this)` and adding that to the radiobutton group in my xml. But again the same issue all buttons getting selected!

Comment: @sriram YOu need to assign a different ID to all of them. I said that was the root problem, remember?

Comment: Yes I do that by `rb.setId(++radioButtonIdCounter);` where `radioButtonIdCounter` is counter which I increment during my for loop! But that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @sriram Can you please post your updated code and let me know. There are several potential problems which can cause this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24104/discussion-between-sriram-and-class-stacker)

Comment: If the above is your new code, then your loop is still wrongly set upo. As I already wrote, _you inflate the layout only once_. The only thing to loop over is the four lines in which you create a radio button, assign its text and id, and add it to the radio group. Do you underdstand the semantics of _inflate_ and _findViewById_?

Comment: Yes I found where I was making mistake. And as far my understand inflate is way in which we can hook into android rendering process and also once I inflate a view and try *findByViewId* then I will be getting the same element! I guess I'm correct. Ain't I? Anyways thanks for the answer!

Comment: @sriram I wouldn't say _inflate_ initiates the rendering. WHat it does is take an XML and create objects from that. You could do the same in code. The real rendering is only done after _onCreate()_ is finished. -- Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you very much...this help me to find the solution to a similar problem.